# D3.time scale keeps returning default value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to use 0:00-23:00 as my x axis label. I have `var x = d3.time.scale().range[0, width];` I want to set its domain to `hour_data` which is an array that stores a list of times, but no matter I try `d3.domain(d3.extent(hour_data, function(d){ return d.hour;}))` or `d3.domain(hour_data.map(function(d){ return d.hour;});`, the domain just keeps at the default GMT time which dates back to 1969.

I only need to print the hours as x axis labels.

Excuse me no formatting the code in blocks. I've been bugged by this error for hours and just don't want the hassle to format code blocks on SO. The code is simple anyway.

Comment: have u seen this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048166

Comment: @Cyril So that code uses a custom format function...That is good, but is it possible to just use d3.time's default functions?

Comment: can you post the contents of hour_data..

Comment: It's in the following format: { hour: 0, value: 10}, where hour is in the range [0, 23]. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean hour_data is an array of that anonymous class.

Comment: well you have to convert your hour: 12 to javascript date object so that the data relates to a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
//this is your data json
var data = [{
  hour: 0,
  value: 10
}, {
  hour: 1,
  value: 10
}, {
  hour: 13,
  value: 10
}, {
  hour: 14,
  value: 20
}, {
  hour: 15,
  value: 20
}]
var width = 700,
  height = 400,
  padding = 100;

// create an svg container
var vis = d3.select("body").
append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);


// define the x scale (horizontal)

var format1 = d3.time.format("%H");
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .nice(d3.time.hour)
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    //conveting the data into date object
    return format1.parse(d.hour + "");
  }))
  .range([padding, width - padding * 2]); // map these the the chart width = total width minus padding at both sides


// define the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .ticks(d3.time.hour, 1)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    hours = d.getHours();
    return hours;
  }).orient("bottom")
  .scale(xScale);

// draw x axis with labels and move to the bottom of the chart area
vis.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis") // give it a class so it can be used to select only xaxis labels  below
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.bar rect {
  fill: steelblue;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar text {
  fill: #fff;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Need to define the timeline as below, full working example snippet

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.domain([parseTime("00:00"), parseTime("23:00")])
.range([pad, w - pad]);
```

```js
var w = 960;
var h = 600;
var pad = 80;

var parseTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M").parse;

var data = [{
    "Time": "04:20",
        "Close": 7
}, {
    "Time": "05:20",
        "Close": 8
}, {
    "Time": "06:20",
        "Close": 9
}, {
    "Time": "07:20",
        "Close": 6
}, {
    "Time": "08:20",
        "Close": 5
}, {
    "Time": "09:20",
        "Close": 7
}, {
    "Time": "10:20",
        "Close": 3
}, {
    "Time": "13:20",
        "Close": 8
}, {
    "Time": "15:20",
        "Close": 9
}, {
    "Time": "18:20",
        "Close": 6
}, {
    "Time": "19:20",
        "Close": 5
}, {
    "Time": "21:20",
        "Close": 7
}, {
    "Time": "22:20",
        "Close": 3
}];

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.Time = parseTime(d.Time);
    d.Close = +d.Close;

});

var x = d3.time.scale()
 .domain([parseTime("00:00"), parseTime("23:00")])
 .range([pad, w - pad]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0,40])
 .range([h - pad, pad]);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
 .orient("bottom")  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));


var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.Time); })
.y(function (d) { return y(d.Close); });


// Add x-axis.
canvas.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform","translate(0," + (h - pad) + ")")
 .call(xaxis)
 
// Add y-axis
canvas.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", 0)")
 .call(yaxis);

canvas.append("path")
 .data([data])
 .attr("d", line).attr("class", "line");
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```